# React Bootstrap Forms: <Form.Control.Feedback></Form.Control.Feedback> is not displaying when validated is false

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

**Issue:**

I'm implementing a form and having a really hard time understanding why the React Bootstrap: `<Form.Control.Feedback></Form.Control.Feedback>` is not displaying when validated is false

**Steps To Reproduce:**

1. When the user clicks the `Send Verification Code` button, `type={'submit'}` a prop on the button and is triggered.
2. `onClick={(event) => sendVerificationCode(event)}` passes the event, where I use `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation();` to stop cancel the event.
3. With nothing entered in the field, the `sendVerificationCode` function correctly works and only logs `console.log('DO NOTHING');` and `console.log(validated);` for testing.
4. `validated` is working and is false, but why isn't the <Form.Control.Feedback></Form.Control.Feedback> not displaying.

**ForgotPassword.tsx**

```
// Page: Forgot Password
const ForgotPassword = () => {
  // React Hooks: State
  const [ email, setEmail ] = useState('');

  // React Hooks: Bootstrap
  const [ validated, setValidated ] = useState(false);

  // React Hooks: Refs
  const formRef: React.RefObject<HTMLFormElement> = useRef(null);

  // React Hooks: Redux
  const authError = useSelector((state: ReduxState) => state.authReducer.error);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // React Hooks: React Router DOM
  let history = useHistory();

  // Send Verification Code
  const sendVerificationCode = (event: any) => {
    console.log('Component: sendVerificationCode working')

    // Event: Cancels Event (Stops HTML Default Form Submit)
    event.preventDefault();

    // Event: Prevents Event Bubbling To Parent Elements
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Check Form Validity
    if (formRef.current && formRef.current.checkValidity()) {
      // Validate Form
      setValidated(true);

      // Redux: Send Verification Code Request
      dispatch(sendVerificationCodeRequest(email, history));
    }
    else {
      // Do Nothing (Form.Control.Feedback Will Appear)
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <NavigationBar />

      <Container id="forgot-password-container">
        <div id="forgot-password-inner-container">
          <div>
            <p id="forgot-password-title">Reset Password</p>
          </div>

          <Form ref={formRef} noValidate validated={validated}>
            <Form.Group controlId="forgot-password-email" className="form-group-container">
              <Form.Label className="form-field-title">Email</Form.Label>

              <Form.Control
                type={'email'}
                placeholder={'Email'}
                className="form-input"
                onChange={(event) => setEmail((event.target.value).toLowerCase())}
                value={email}
                maxLength={50}
                required
              />

              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Invalid email</Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Button
              variant={'primary'}
              type={'submit'}
              id="login-button"
              onClick={(event) => sendVerificationCode(event)}
            >Send Verification Code</Button>
          </Form>

          <div id="login-sign-up-container">
            <p id="login-need-account-text">Need an account?</p>
            <button id="login-sign-up-button" type="button" onClick={() => history.push('sign-up')}>Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

// Exports
export default ForgotPassword;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation), React Bootstrap's logic is that they actually set the `validated` prop of the `Form` to `true` regardless of whether or not the inputs are valid.

According to the [prop definition of validated](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#form-props):

> Mark a form as having been validated. Setting it to true will toggle
> any validation styles on the forms elements.

So to solve your issue, just take out `setValidated` out of the condition statement and put it somewhere below, for example, event.stopPropagation()

```
const sendVerificationCode = (event: any) => {
    console.log('Component: sendVerificationCode working')

    // Event: Cancels Event (Stops HTML Default Form Submit)
    event.preventDefault();

    // Event: Prevents Event Bubbling To Parent Elements
    event.stopPropagation();

    setValidated(true);

    ...
```

Comment: Ahhh that was it. Thanks for the clarification! That one was getting to me for a while